# Android Contacts Manager not displaying

Tags: android

I am creating an Android Contacts manager and this is my MainActvity class. When I run the app, it comes with an error message without even displaying the screen. Here my MainActivity.java code. Was wondering what the issue is.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

/*
 * This is the Main Activity and the Home screen to the application. This screen will display
 * the list of all the contacts. Once various buttons/icons are pressed, different screens/activities
 * will be displayed.
 */
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Initializing the listView and the contactList. The contactList is made public so that it is
    // accessible from any class.

    private TextView contactId;


    //The object that allows me to manipulate the Database
    DBTools dbTools = new DBTools(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfContacts = dbTools.getAllContacts();



        // Checking to make sure that there are contacts to display.
        // Then setting up the view of the Home Screen
        if(listOfContacts.size()!=0){
            setupListView(listOfContacts);
        }

    }

    private void setupListView(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfContacts){

        ListView listView = getListView();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            // Once any contact is clicked, the details are passed as extra information for
            // the ViewContactsDetails class (using a Bundle). The application is then taken to
            // the ViewContactDetails screen.
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View clickedView, int clickedViewPosition, long id){

                //When an item is clicked get the TextView with matching checkId

                contactId = (TextView) clickedView.findViewById(R.id.contactId);

                //Convert that contactId into a String

                String contactIdValue = contactId.getText().toString();

                // Intention to go to the ViewContactDetails class/screen

                Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), ViewContactDetails.class);
                // Put additional data in for EditContact to use

                theIntent.putExtra("contactId", contactIdValue);

                // calls for ViewContactDetails

                startActivity(theIntent);

            }

        });

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, listOfContacts, R.layout.contact_entry, new String[] {"contactId", "lastName", "firstName"}, new int[] {R.id.contactId, R.id.lastName, R.id.firstName});

        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        // Once the add contact button is pressed, the application is taken to the AddContact screen.
        case R.id.addImageButton:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddContact.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            break;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The error in logCat is:

```
10-17 14:55:01.873: D/dalvikvm(1310): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 69K, 8% free 2779K/3008K, paused 35ms, total 39ms
10-17 14:55:01.883: I/dalvikvm-heap(1310): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.939MB for 1127536-byte allocation
10-17 14:55:01.933: D/dalvikvm(1310): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 3877K/4112K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
10-17 14:55:02.023: D/AndroidRuntime(1310): Shutting down VM
10-17 14:55:02.033: W/dalvikvm(1310): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dgop507.softeng206.contactsmanagerapplication/dgop507.softeng206.contactsmanagerapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at dgop507.softeng206.contactsmanagerapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-17 14:55:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: And we are wondering what is the error message.

Comment: when you run the simulator. It just says the app has encountered a problem (and closes) without displaying the main screen

Comment: If you are using Eclipse the errors are in the LogCat. Post it.

Comment: have posted the errors appearing in LogCat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is:

> Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

To use `ListView listView = getListView();` you must have a `ListView` in your layout with this attribute: `android:id="@android:id/list"`